# SAS - create data step variables using a dynamic macro-variable

Tags: sas

I want to store an instance of a data step variable in a macro-variable using call symput, then use that macro-variable in the same data step to populate a new field, assigning it a new value every 36 records.

I tried the following code:

```
data a;
set a;
if MOB = 1 then do;
   MOB1_accounts = accounts;
   call symput('MOB1_acct', MOB1_accounts);
end;
else if MOB > 1 then MOB1_accounts = &MOB1_acct.;
run;
```

I have a series of repeating MOB's (1-36). I want to create a field called MOB1_Accts, set it equal to the # of accounts for that cohort where MOB = 1, and keep that value when MOB = 2, 3, 4 etc. I basically want to "drag down" the MOB 1 value every 36 records.

For some reason this macro-variable is returning "1" instead of the correct # accounts. I think it might be a char/numeric issue but unsure. I've tried every possible permutation of single quotes, double quotes, symget, etc... no luck.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misusing the macro system.

The ampersand (`&`) introducer in source code tells SAS to resolve the following symbol and place it into the code submission stream.  Thus, the resolved `&MOB1_acct.` **can not** be changed in the running DATA Step.  In other words, a running step can not change it's source code -- The resolved macro variable will be the same for all implicit iterations of the step because its value became part of the source code of the step.

You can use `SYMPUT()` and `SYMGET()` functions to move strings out of and into a DATA Step.  But that is still the wrong approach for your problem.

The most straight forward technique could be

- use of a `retain`ed variable
- `mod (_n_, 36)` computation to determine every 36<sup>th</sup> row.  (`_n_` is a proxy for row number in a simple step with a single SET.)

Example:

```
data a;
  set a;

  retain mob1_accounts;

  * every 36 rows change the value, otherwise the value is retained;
  if mod(_n_,36) = 1 then mob1_accounts = accounts;
run;
```

You didn't show any data, so the actual program statements you need might be slightly different.

**Contrasting `SYMPUT/SYMGET` with `RETAIN`**

As stated, `SYMPUT/SYMGET` is a possible way to *retain* values by off storing them in the macro symbol table.  There is a penalty though.  The `SYM*` requires a function call and whatever machinations/blackbox goings on are happening to store/retrieve a symbol value, and possibly additional conversions between character and numeric.

Example:

1,000,000 rows read. `DATA _null_` steps to avoid writing overhead as part of contrast.

```
data have;
  do rownum = 1 to 1e6;
    mob + 1;
    accounts = sum(accounts, rand('integer', 1,50) - 10);
    if mob > 36 then mob = 1;
    output;
  end;
run;

data _null_;
  set have;

  if mob = 1 then call symput ('mob1_accounts', cats(accounts));

  mob1_accounts = symgetn('mob1_accounts');
run;

data _null_;
  set have;
  retain mob1_accounts;

  if mob = 1 then mob1_accounts = accounts;
run;
```

On my system logs

```
142  data _null_;
143    set have;
144
145    if mob = 1 then call symput ('mob1_accounts', cats(accounts));
146
147    mob1_accounts = symgetn('mob1_accounts');
148  run;

NOTE: There were 1000000 observations read from the data set WORK.HAVE.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.34 seconds
      cpu time            0.34 seconds


149
150  data _null_;
151    set have;
152    retain mob1_accounts;
153
154    if mob = 1 then mob1_accounts = accounts;
155  run;

NOTE: There were 1000000 observations read from the data set WORK.HAVE.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.04 seconds
      cpu time            0.03 seconds
```

Or

```
   way          real   cpu
------------- ------  ----
SYMPUT/SYMGET   0.34  0.34
    RETAIN      0.04  0.03
```

Comment: For some reason my call symput + symget/symgetn is still returning only "1". But the retain statement worked perfectly. I don't know how I hadn't heard of it until now - thanks so much!